# Use Pagination in a Mediawiki Image Gallery or Table

Tags: mediawiki

I'm looking for a way to either paginate a MediaWiki image gallery (made with `<gallery>` tags) or paginate a table after a certain number of entries. I know the `TablePager` class in MediaWiki exists and a variation is used to create the same desired effect on category pages.

I have not found any examples of this being done on other wikis or any extensions. Is there an extension I've missed, or another potential solution through CSS or JS?

EDIT:

For future reference, I was able to add a pager to an html table via a jQuery pagination plugin pasted into Common.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, you would have to implement your own gallery mode class and get it into MediaWiki core, similar to the options here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Gallery_tag

Comment: Thank you! Out of curiosity, what would the process be for paginating tables then?

Comment: You can use a javascript library, I've used the jquery tablesorter pages plugin before